# Copy files between RDC

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I need to copy a file from one remote desktop to another.
The problem is that the second remote desktop does not have a windows GUI - I can only use limited functions.
Can I use cmd - can I try **xcopy** or **robocopy** or is there an easier way?
Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

**\Server\c$\Path\to\folder\data**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).